# Most appropriate analysis for non-normal, right-censored response variable?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, normality-assumption

I conducted an experiment with human subjects in which the independent variable has 3 treatment levels and the dependent variable is the duration of time that passes before the subject engages in a specific action of interest. The minimum duration is 0 seconds and the maximum is 900 seconds (i.e., 15 minutes, at which point the experimenter ends the experiment).

It seems I could use a nonparametric text like Wilcoxon rank sum (to conduct pairwise comparisons), but I'm not sure if this is the most sensitive/appropriate test I could use. I know survival analysis is sometimes used, but again not sure if it's better or more appropriate than a nonparametric test.

I'd also like to know if there is an advantage to using a survival analysis/log-rank test over the Wilcoxon rank sum (aka Mann-Whitney U test).

Finally, I'm not clear on how to run the survival analysis.

Comment: [This question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/207435/28500) seems almost identical to yours. Note that with 3 treatment levels in your case your question should be about using Kruskal-Wallis versus survival analysis, not Mann-Whitney versus survival analysis. Please look at the question and answer I linked, and edit your question to ask specifically about things they don't answer for you.

Comment: @EdM, I have 3 groups, but I'm interested in making a series of pairwise comparisons. The answer to the other question is helpful, but it doesn't indicate whether/why survival analysis is better than something like Mann-Whitney. Also, I am having a lot of trouble finding information on how to run the survival analysis in R (how the data should be set up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/207435/28500) suggests, in this type of case with all censoring at the same time after all of the "events" have occurred, the log-rank survival test and the non-parametric tests like Mann-Whitney should be essentially equivalent, perhaps except for some differences in how tied ranks/times are handled.

The advantage of survival analysis is that it's designed specifically for this type of situation and can provide the often-appropriate proportional hazards regression as an option. In R you need to have a data frame with one row per individual, a column for the treatment (coded as a factor variable), columns for any other predictor variables, a column for the event time (or last follow-up time, 900 seconds in your case), and a column indicating whether the time corresponds to an event (1) or censoring (0). Note that this coding of censoring can differ among software packages (it's opposite for MATLAB as I recall).

The regression is then done with a `Surv` object as provided by the R `survival` package as the dependent variable. The `survdiff` function does this with a non-parametric test, the `coxph` function under the proportional hazards assumption.

With 3 treatment groups the standard procedure is to test first whether there are any differences among groups with a global test, then to do between-group comparisons with correction for the multiple comparisons.

Comment: Thanks, @EdM. Is there an advantage to using survdiff vs coxph? I am not sure if the proportional hazards assumption is appropriate for my data. Also, I don't understand the test enough to know if it's one-sided or two? Can the p-value be halved given a directional hypothesis (that one group will do more poorly on average)?\

Comment: With `coxph` you get relative magnitudes of effects, not just that treatment effects differ, and it allows for multiple regression and interactions. Tools in the `survival` package can test the proportional hazards assumption. A web search of "r survival analysis" will show links to many freely available explanations, if the documentation in `survival` isn't enough. Normally, the null hypothesis is that there are no differences among treatments, with a 2-sided test of that hypothesis. I'm reluctant to give advice on pre-specified directional hypotheses.

Answer (score 2):

I think EdM answered your question about what analysis to do. Regarding implementation, [*Introducing Survival and Event History Analysis*](https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/eur/introducing-survival-and-event-history-analysis/book233417) by Melinda Mills is an excellent introduction to survival analysis in R. It is aimed at beginners in R and includes an entire chapter on formatting your data (which is half the battle).

Comment: I've ordered the book - thanks! Most of what I've come across on the internet has been really difficult to understand (and I'm not terribly slow), so I'm looking forward to an accessible intro.